# How can I convert multiple label variables into a dictionary in tkinter using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, tkinter

so I have these buttons in my program and I want them to be in a dictionary instead of them being in a separate value,
buttons are all the same for now , but they will change later in the code so thats why I'm making them separate values

```
answer_1_1 = tk.Label(base_frame, text='', fg='black', bg='white', highlightbackground='#d3d6da', highlightthickness=2, font = ('Helvetica', 32, 'bold'))
answer_1_2 = tk.Label(base_frame, text='', fg='black', bg='white', highlightbackground='#d3d6da', highlightthickness=2, font = ('Helvetica', 32, 'bold'))
answer_1_3 = tk.Label(base_frame, text='', fg='black', bg='white', highlightbackground='#d3d6da', highlightthickness=2, font = ('Helvetica', 32, 'bold'))
answer_1_4 = tk.Label(base_frame, text='', fg='black', bg='white', highlightbackground='#d3d6da', highlightthickness=2, font = ('Helvetica', 32, 'bold'))
answer_1_5 = tk.Label(base_frame, text='', fg='black', bg='white', highlightbackground='#d3d6da', highlightthickness=2, font = ('Helvetica', 32, 'bold'))

answer_2_1 = tk.Label(base_frame, text='', fg='black', bg='white', highlightbackground='#d3d6da', highlightthickness=2, font = ('Helvetica', 32, 'bold'))
answer_2_2 = tk.Label(base_frame, text='', fg='black', bg='white', highlightbackground='#d3d6da', highlightthickness=2, font = ('Helvetica', 32, 'bold'))
answer_2_3 = tk.Label(base_frame, text='', fg='black', bg='white', highlightbackground='#d3d6da', highlightthickness=2, font = ('Helvetica', 32, 'bold'))
answer_2_4 = tk.Label(base_frame, text='', fg='black', bg='white', highlightbackground='#d3d6da', highlightthickness=2, font = ('Helvetica', 32, 'bold'))
answer_2_5 = tk.Label(base_frame, text='', fg='black', bg='white', highlightbackground='#d3d6da', highlightthickness=2, font = ('Helvetica', 32, 'bold'))

answer_3_1 = tk.Label(base_frame, text='', fg='black', bg='white', highlightbackground='#d3d6da', highlightthickness=2, font = ('Helvetica', 32, 'bold'))
answer_3_2 = tk.Label(base_frame, text='', fg='black', bg='white', highlightbackground='#d3d6da', highlightthickness=2, font = ('Helvetica', 32, 'bold'))
answer_3_3 = tk.Label(base_frame, text='', fg='black', bg='white', highlightbackground='#d3d6da', highlightthickness=2, font = ('Helvetica', 32, 'bold'))
answer_3_4 = tk.Label(base_frame, text='', fg='black', bg='white', highlightbackground='#d3d6da', highlightthickness=2, font = ('Helvetica', 32, 'bold'))
answer_3_5 = tk.Label(base_frame, text='', fg='black', bg='white', highlightbackground='#d3d6da', highlightthickness=2, font = ('Helvetica', 32, 'bold'))

answer_4_1 = tk.Label(base_frame, text='', fg='black', bg='white', highlightbackground='#d3d6da', highlightthickness=2, font = ('Helvetica', 32, 'bold'))
answer_4_2 = tk.Label(base_frame, text='', fg='black', bg='white', highlightbackground='#d3d6da', highlightthickness=2, font = ('Helvetica', 32, 'bold'))
answer_4_3 = tk.Label(base_frame, text='', fg='black', bg='white', highlightbackground='#d3d6da', highlightthickness=2, font = ('Helvetica', 32, 'bold'))
answer_4_4 = tk.Label(base_frame, text='', fg='black', bg='white', highlightbackground='#d3d6da', highlightthickness=2, font = ('Helvetica', 32, 'bold'))
answer_4_5 = tk.Label(base_frame, text='', fg='black', bg='white', highlightbackground='#d3d6da', highlightthickness=2, font = ('Helvetica', 32, 'bold'))

answer_5_1 = tk.Label(base_frame, text='', fg='black', bg='white', highlightbackground='#d3d6da', highlightthickness=2, font = ('Helvetica', 32, 'bold'))
answer_5_2 = tk.Label(base_frame, text='', fg='black', bg='white', highlightbackground='#d3d6da', highlightthickness=2, font = ('Helvetica', 32, 'bold'))
answer_5_3 = tk.Label(base_frame, text='', fg='black', bg='white', highlightbackground='#d3d6da', highlightthickness=2, font = ('Helvetica', 32, 'bold'))
answer_5_4 = tk.Label(base_frame, text='', fg='black', bg='white', highlightbackground='#d3d6da', highlightthickness=2, font = ('Helvetica', 32, 'bold'))
answer_5_5 = tk.Label(base_frame, text='', fg='black', bg='white', highlightbackground='#d3d6da', highlightthickness=2, font = ('Helvetica', 32, 'bold'))

answer_6_1 = tk.Label(base_frame, text='', fg='black', bg='white', highlightbackground='#d3d6da', highlightthickness=2, font = ('Helvetica', 32, 'bold'))
answer_6_2 = tk.Label(base_frame, text='', fg='black', bg='white', highlightbackground='#d3d6da', highlightthickness=2, font = ('Helvetica', 32, 'bold'))
answer_6_3 = tk.Label(base_frame, text='', fg='black', bg='white', highlightbackground='#d3d6da', highlightthickness=2, font = ('Helvetica', 32, 'bold'))
answer_6_4 = tk.Label(base_frame, text='', fg='black', bg='white', highlightbackground='#d3d6da', highlightthickness=2, font = ('Helvetica', 32, 'bold'))
answer_6_5 = tk.Label(base_frame, text='', fg='black', bg='white', highlightbackground='#d3d6da', highlightthickness=2, font = ('Helvetica', 32, 'bold'))

answer_1_1.grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = 'nesw', padx = 2.5, pady = 2.5)
answer_1_2.grid(row = 1, column = 2, sticky = 'nesw', padx = 2.5, pady = 2.5)
answer_1_3.grid(row = 1, column = 3, sticky = 'nesw', padx = 2.5, pady = 2.5)
answer_1_4.grid(row = 1, column = 4, sticky = 'nesw', padx = 2.5, pady = 2.5)
answer_1_5.grid(row = 1, column = 5, sticky = 'nesw', padx = 2.5, pady = 2.5)

answer_2_1.grid(row = 2, column = 1, sticky = 'nesw', padx = 2.5, pady = 2.5)
answer_2_2.grid(row = 2, column = 2, sticky = 'nesw', padx = 2.5, pady = 2.5)
answer_2_3.grid(row = 2, column = 3, sticky = 'nesw', padx = 2.5, pady = 2.5)
answer_2_4.grid(row = 2, column = 4, sticky = 'nesw', padx = 2.5, pady = 2.5)
answer_2_5.grid(row = 2, column = 5, sticky = 'nesw', padx = 2.5, pady = 2.5)

answer_3_1.grid(row = 3, column = 1, sticky = 'nesw', padx = 2.5, pady = 2.5)
answer_3_2.grid(row = 3, column = 2, sticky = 'nesw', padx = 2.5, pady = 2.5)
answer_3_3.grid(row = 3, column = 3, sticky = 'nesw', padx = 2.5, pady = 2.5)
answer_3_4.grid(row = 3, column = 4, sticky = 'nesw', padx = 2.5, pady = 2.5)
answer_3_5.grid(row = 3, column = 5, sticky = 'nesw', padx = 2.5, pady = 2.5)

answer_4_1.grid(row = 4, column = 1, sticky = 'nesw', padx = 2.5, pady = 2.5)
answer_4_2.grid(row = 4, column = 2, sticky = 'nesw', padx = 2.5, pady = 2.5)
answer_4_3.grid(row = 4, column = 3, sticky = 'nesw', padx = 2.5, pady = 2.5)
answer_4_4.grid(row = 4, column = 4, sticky = 'nesw', padx = 2.5, pady = 2.5)
answer_4_5.grid(row = 4, column = 5, sticky = 'nesw', padx = 2.5, pady = 2.5)

answer_5_1.grid(row = 5, column = 1, sticky = 'nesw', padx = 2.5, pady = 2.5)
answer_5_2.grid(row = 5, column = 2, sticky = 'nesw', padx = 2.5, pady = 2.5)
answer_5_3.grid(row = 5, column = 3, sticky = 'nesw', padx = 2.5, pady = 2.5)
answer_5_4.grid(row = 5, column = 4, sticky = 'nesw', padx = 2.5, pady = 2.5)
answer_5_5.grid(row = 5, column = 5, sticky = 'nesw', padx = 2.5, pady = 2.5)

answer_6_1.grid(row = 6, column = 1, sticky = 'nesw', padx = 2.5, pady = 2.5)
answer_6_2.grid(row = 6, column = 2, sticky = 'nesw', padx = 2.5, pady = 2.5)
answer_6_3.grid(row = 6, column = 3, sticky = 'nesw', padx = 2.5, pady = 2.5)
answer_6_4.grid(row = 6, column = 4, sticky = 'nesw', padx = 2.5, pady = 2.5)
answer_6_5.grid(row = 6, column = 5, sticky = 'nesw', padx = 2.5, pady = 2.5)
```

I want them to be like this :

```
dict = {'answer1': tk.Label(base_frame, text='', fg='black', bg='white', highlightbackground='#d3d6da', highlightthickness=2, font = ('Helvetica', 32, 'bold')),
        'answer2': tk.Label(base_frame, text='', fg='black', bg='white', highlightbackground='#d3d6da', highlightthickness=2, font = ('Helvetica', 32, 'bold')),
        ...
        }
```

any ideas on how to do this with a for loop and how to access the buttons in the dictionary?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more on what you want to achieve? Obviously it is not just about storing them into a dict, since you showed us that you already know how to do this.

Comment: I want to store these labels to a dictionary with a for loop , I dont know how to do this , and is this efficient or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: It all depends on the context of your application. Like is it a finite or infinite number of questions. Do you need to have these *empty lables" shown in the first place ? Note well that the size of the labels change with the content you put in. So your question isn't clear to me. What are you searching for ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest the following structure - create a nested loop where the external loop is the questions and the internal one is the answers per question. For each answer, create a button (`curr_button`) and save it in a dictionary. The dictionary is a nested dictionary where there is a key per question which is a dictionary itself with keys for each answer.

```
from itertools import product 
from collections import defaultdict

num_questions = 6
answers_per_question = 4

buttons_dict = defaultdict(dict)

for q in range(1, num_questions+1):
    for a in range(1, answers_per_question+1):
        curr_button = tk.Label(base_frame, text='', fg='black', bg='white', highlightbackground='#d3d6da', highlightthickness=2, font = ('Helvetica', 32, 'bold'))
        curr_button.grid(row = q, column = a, sticky = 'nesw', padx = 2.5, pady = 2.5)
        buttons_dict[q][a]=curr_button
```

Comment: thank you so much for the answer! it completely works , but I have a question , I'm new to dictionaries so how can I for example get the first button (row = 0, column = 0) from the dictionary and configure it?

Comment: I got it , I needed to do buttons_dict[1][1] , thank you for your answer! just what I needed

Comment: I did it (1, 1) since it followed the example, but you can change to be 0 based using `for q in range(num_questions)... ` and similarly to the inner loop

Answer (score 1):

To give an example of how you basically code an efficient Q&A app.
Create just what you need and use the appropriate techs to achieve it.

For the sake of self-study, here is an example:

```
import tkinter as tk

q_and_a = {
    'How old are you?' : [
        16, #0
        18, #1
        21, #2
        48],#3
    'Where do you live?' : [
        'USA',
        'India',
        'England',
        'Syria'],
    }

right_answer = {
    'How old are you?' : 0,
    'Where do you live?' : 2,
    }

def generate_q_and_a():
    for k,v in q_and_a.items():
        yield k,v
generator = generate_q_and_a()

def next_question():
    try:
        q, a = next(generator)
    except StopIteration:
        print('all questions have solved')
        root.destroy()
    else:
        question.config(text = q)
        for idx,child in enumerate(answer_frame.winfo_children()):
            child.config(text=a[idx])

def answer_selected(n):
    current_question = question.cget('text')
    valid = n == right_answer[current_question]
    if valid:
        next_question()
    else:
        print('wrong answer')

BACKGROUND = 'grey'
FOREGROUND = 'black'

root = tk.Tk()
#content of root
question = tk.Label(
    root, text='', bg=BACKGROUND, fg=FOREGROUND, relief=tk.RIDGE)
answer_frame = tk.Frame(
    root, bg = BACKGROUND, borderwidth=2, relief=tk.SUNKEN)
#geometry of root
question.pack(fill=tk.X, expand=True)
answer_frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
#content of answer_frame
choice_config = {
    'master' : answer_frame,
    'text' : '',
    'relief' : tk.RAISED,
    'borderwidth' : 1,
    'background' : 'grey',
    'foreground' : 'white',
    }
for i in range(4):
    callback = lambda n=i: answer_selected(n)
    choice = tk.Button(**choice_config, command=callback)
    choice.pack(fill=tk.X, expand=True)
#start application
next_question()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I'm sorry , but the program is wordle , and the answer labels are where you need to guess the word , I should've wrote the question more clearly, but thank you for your answer!

Comment: @Aeen no worries. However I would advice you to study this bit of code and tweak it to fit your needs.

Comment: I definitely will , thanks!